# Metabelian—the derived subgroup of the product of two Abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

> $G=AB$, where $A$, $B$ are abelian subgroups. Then $G’$ is abelian.

**Attempt:**

$\color{red}{\text{Suppose }B \text{ to be normal.}}$

$G/B=AB/B\cong A/(A\cap B)$, where $A/(A\cap B)$ is definitely abelian, hence $G/B$ is an abelian group. There’s a well-known proposition:

> **Proposition:** *Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then* 
>   $$G/N \mbox{ is Abelian}~~~\Longleftrightarrow ~~~G’\leq N. $$

Therefore $G’\leq B$, where $B$ is an abelian group, and then we get $G’$ is abelian as desired.

Whereas, the only weakness is that $B$ is not necessarily normal. Actually, since $G=AB=BA$, it suffices to prove the normality of one of the two abelian subgroups, but it’s precisely where I’m stuck.

Am I basically right? Or do I need to take another idea? Any hint or detail will be sincerely welcome. I’d be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct, but probably will not suffice. 
The claim follows from **Ito's Theorem**, saying that if $G=AB$, then $G$ is metabelian, i.e., that $G'$ is abelian:

Ito's original proof is very simple and straightforward:

- Itô, Noboru.
  "Über das Produkt von zwei abelschen Gruppen."
  Math. Z. 62 (1955), 400–401.
  MR[71426](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=71426)
  DOI:[10.1007/BF01180647](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01180647)

For several duplicates on MSE, proving Ito's Theorem, see for example here:

[Commutator property in product of groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120472/commutator-property-in-product-of-groups)

There are also several generalizations of Ito's result, e.g., the following:

**Theorem:** *Let $G=AB$ be a group with abelian subgroup $A$ and nilpotent, metabelian subgroup $B$. Then $G$ is solvable of derived length at most $4$.*

For details see my paper [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_48_derived_lie.pdf).

Comment: The proof is reproduced in many other papers on this topic. You can use the proof given by Jack Schmidt (at the duplicate). I had another link, but cannot find it now.

Comment: Here is another reference: ([AFG], Theorem $2.1.1$, the book by Amberg et al., see [here](http://www.cgt2015.unina.it/centro/talk/Amberg.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m grateful for your time!