# Product of two Abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

**My Question :**

> $G=AB$, where $A,\, B$ are abelian groups. Are $A$ and $B$ normal?

The problem is a very basic, and very much possibly duplicate of an existing question in this community.

But my question actually might have gone a different way......

---

I post [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676323/a-question-about-the-proof-of-itos-theorem-metabelian/2677680#2677680) today. When I check it, I found in the final part that $[a,b]^{a'} = [a, b^{a'}] \in [A,B]$ may imply $ b^{a’}\in B,\,\forall a’\in A,\, b\in B $. So $B$ is invariant under conjugations by elements of $A$, and $B$ is hence normal, since $G=AB$. The same is true for $[a,b]^{b'} $.

---

I know my statement is wrong, but what have I misunderstood? Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: The error in your reasoning is simply that $[a,b^{a'}] \in [A,B]$ does not imply that $b^{a'} \in B$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes. I’ve got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example, the Klein bottle group (that is, the fundamental group of a Klein bottle) is given by $G=\langle a, b; a^{-1}ba=b^{-1}\rangle$. Here, $A=\langle a\rangle$ and $B=\langle b\rangle$. Clearly, $G=AB$. However, $A$ is not normal in $G$.

This group can be viewed as $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$, where the action of one infinite cyclic group on the other is to negate it: $b\mapsto b^{-1}$. If the action was trivial then we would have a direct rather than semidirect product, so $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, which is clearly abelian so all subgroups are normal.

---

The above is rather complicated. For a simpler example, consider the smallest non-abelian group. This is also the smallest counter-example to your question.

Comment: Thanks! I know my statement is wrong. What have I misunderstood in the process?

Comment: $[a,b^{a'}]\in [A,B]$ does not imply $b^{a'}\in B$.

Comment: @Levent Thanks, but why? I believed it’s the weakness, but I have not been able to figure out why.

Comment: @Benny I suggest you think about my second example. Do you know which group I am referring to?...

Comment: @user1729 I’ve not learned semidirect product...

Comment: Well, there is no example of this in the above Klein bottle group. But I believe this should lead to an example : Consider $G=\langle a,b\mid [a,b^a]=1 \rangle$. Then $1=[a,b^a]\in [A,B]$ but $b^a$ is not in $B$.

Comment: @Benny After that - what is the smallest non-abelian group?

Comment: @user1729 $S_3$

Comment: @Benny Well, $S_3$, which has order $6$. Then take $A=\{(12), e\}$ and $B=\{(123), (132), e\}$. One is normal, but the other is not (which is which?!?). Also, $G=AB$ (why?).

Comment: @Levent Thanks! I got it!

Comment: @user1729 $B$ is, $A$ not. $B\triangleleft G$, $AB$ is a group. However, $(|A|,|B|)=1$, the intersection is hence trivial, $|AB|=\dfrac{2\cdot 3}{1}=6=|G|$.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks! +1 from me!