# Is the specific group abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ is a group, such that there exist two its normal abelian subgroups $A$ and $B$, satisfying the condition $G = AB = \{ab | a \in A, b \in B\}$. Is $G$ always abelian?

The statement is true if the intersection of A and B is trivial, due to the obvious fact that for each $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ we have $[a, b]$ lying in $A \cap B$ (because both subgroups are normal).

It is also quite easy to conclude from that, that $G$ is always metabelian.

However, I do not know how to proceed further.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should try and think of a counterexample - try groups of order $8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $G=AB$ with $A,B$ abelian subgroups implies that $G$ is metabelian by Ito's Theorem, but not that $G$ is abelian, see here:

[A question about the proof of Ito's theorem (Metabelian)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676323/a-question-about-the-proof-of-itos-theorem-metabelian)

[Commutator property in product of groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120472/commutator-property-in-product-of-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Even if we assume that $A,B$ are normal subgroups, $G$ need not be abelian. Consider non-abelian groups where all proper subgroups are normal.